# grafana dynamic variable use

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

suppose i want to change the color of the panel text based on a logic for example if
active users are 3 and open issue is 6 then since we 2 issue per person color should be yellow and if open issue becomes 9 then then based on active user color should be red
yellow=active user*2
red= active user*3
how can i implement it
using variables  and i am using  prompetheus as data source
and metrice for active user is
active_users{users="activeusers"}
Open issue metice
redmine_project_open_issues_total_count{projectname="Redmine Dashboard"}

Comment: active user multiply by 2 =yellow

Comment: active user multiply by 3=red